# How do I externalize property values for an Angular 7 application?

Tags: angular, docker, kubernetes, properties-file

I have an Angular 7 application where the `app.module.ts` files looks like the following. Note that in this example, there are 2 modules with each having 1 key whose value needs to be externalized. By `externalized`, I mean the values should be acquired from the environment at runtime.

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [ ... ],
 imports: [
  SomeModule.forRoot({ apiKey1: "needs to be externalized" }),
  AnotherModule.forRoot({ apiKey2: "needs to also be externalized" })
 ],
 providers: [ ... ],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What I do is build this application (e.g. `ng build` and then containerize it using Docker). At deployment time, the `DevOps` person wants to run the docker container as follows.

```
docker run -e API_KEY_1='somekey' -e API_KEY_2='anotherkey' -p 80:80 my-container:production
```

Note that `API_KEY_1` should map to `apiKey1` and `API_KEY_2` should map to `apiKey2`.

Is there any disciplined way of externalizing values for an Angular application?

I thought about writing a helper script to do string substitution against the file, but I think this approach is not very disciplined (as the transpiled Angular app files are obfuscated and minified). The script would run at container startup, read the environment variables (key and value), and then look at the files to replace the old values with the ones from the environment.

Eventually, the Angular app will be orchestrated with Kubernetes. I'm wondering if there's anything there that might help or influence how to externalize the values in a best practice way.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How about creating a `credentials.json` when the container starts? you can put every key-value pair as json, in `assets/` path or elsewhere. Then angular app can get it with AJAX call(`GET /assets/credentials.json`).

Comment: Oh, my answer could be dangerous that user can get the value in Network tab of Chrome inspector. If you can encrpt the json and decrpyt it on runtime, the app can safely fetch the api keys.

Comment: @kuroneko0441 The thing is  that the Angular modules show code examples where the keys are placed in `app.module.ts`. This stuff gets pushed to `js` files and if someone really wanted to, they can reformat and study the `js` files and grab them (or as you stated, observe the traffic). I think your concern is valid (encryption/decryption) and related; but this post is about externalizing these values so that wherever the app is deployed, the deployment process can inject them via environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a substitution in custom entry-point.

```sh
FROM nginx

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install gettext-base nginx-extras

ADD docker-entrypoint.sh /
ADD settings.json.template /

COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

With a `docker-entrypoint.sh` like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

envsubst < "settings.json.template" > "settings.json"
cp settings.json /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/

# Launch nginx
exec "$@"
```

And a `settings.json.template`:

```
{
  "apiKey2": "$API_KEY_2",
  "apiKey1": "$API_KEY_1"
}
```

Then on your source you add a file
`settings-loader.ts`

```
export const settingsLoader = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
  const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const method = 'GET';
  const url = './assets/settings.json';

  xmlhttp.open(method, url, true);

  xmlhttp.onload = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
      const _environment = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      resolve(_environment);
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  };

  xmlhttp.send();
});
```

And on your `main.ts`:

```
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import {AppModule} from './app/app.module';
import {environment} from './environments/environment';
import {settingsLoader} from 'settings-loader';

settingsLoader.then((settings) => {
  if (settings != null) {
    environment.settings = Object.assign(environment.settings, settings);
  }

  if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
  }

  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Then you should have access in your code with

```
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';

console.log(environment.settings.apiKey1);
```

Comment: This approach works for services/components after dependency injection, but will it work for during or before dependency injection at the `@NgModule` level? If we are doing `envsubt` already then, I would say that in general, at startup, just do a one time substitution against all the generated file (no need for extra code with `settingsLoader` above).